# In Ansible, how to access extra arguments supplied to playbook in callback plugins?

Tags: python, ansible

I'm trying to write a callback plugin that will time each task. That wasn't the tough part.
But I've a series of playbooks that run to provision and configure an instance. For each run of a sequence, I want to pass a runID to each playbook and that runID is constant for one run, something like this:

```
ansible-playbook -e "runID=seq198837" provision.yml
ansible-playbook -e "runID=seq198837" build.yml
ansible-playbook -e "runID=seq198837" deploy.yml
```

The callback plugin I'm writing has to collect time information for each task in a plugin, label them with the runID and deposit them to a logging agent.

I've tried several hooks and events in the callback plugin but am unable to get the runID extra argument passed to the playbook. Is there any way to access that variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get it from `play` object, and you can access that inside `on_play_start`.

Like this:

```
def v2_playbook_on_play_start(self, play):
    vm = play.get_variable_manager()
    extra_vars = vm.extra_vars
    self.run_id = extra_vars['runID']
```

And then, when you dump your results somewhere in `on_stats` (for example), you can refer `self.run_id` to access your `runID` extra variable.